# I can´t get my -/+ button to work (calculator)

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I am learning Java. I am programming a calculator for practice, but I can´t get the <kbd>+/-</kbd> button to work. The button is supposed to make the number negative/positive. If you for example type `5 + 3` and want `3` to be `-3`, it just removes `5+` and only displays `-3`.

Below is the code:

**Calculator class:**

```
package me.lommeregner.main;

public class Main {

  public static String tal = "";  //tal means number
  public static float first = 0;
  public static float second = 0;
  public static int operator;
  static float oper = 0;
  static JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
  public static boolean minplu = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,40 ));
    Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);

    final Button jbn0 = new Button("0", 0);
    final Button jbn1 = new Button("1", 1);
    final Button jbn2 = new Button("2", 2);
    final Button jbn3 = new Button("3", 3);
    final Button jbn4 = new Button("4", 4);
    final Button jbn5 = new Button("5", 5);
    final Button jbn6 = new Button("6", 6);
    final Button jbn7 = new Button("7", 7);
    final Button jbn8 = new Button("8", 8);
    final Button jbn9 = new Button("9", 9);


    final Button jbKomma = new Button(".");
    final Button jbnepo = new Button("+/-"); //the button i need help with



    final Button jbPlus = new Button(" + ");
    final Button jbMinus = new Button(" - ");
    final Button jbGange = new Button(" * ");
    final Button jbDivition = new Button(" / ");
    final Button jbClear = new Button("C");
    final Button jbClearEntity = new Button("CE");
    final Button jbErLigMed = new Button(" = ");



    //North
    JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
    panelNorth.add(jtf);

    //East
    JPanel panelEast = new JPanel();
    panelEast.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    panelEast.add(jbPlus);
    panelEast.add(jbMinus);
    panelEast.add(jbGange);
    panelEast.add(jbDivition);
    panelEast.add(jbErLigMed);
    panelEast.add(jbClear);
    panelEast.add(jbClearEntity);


    //Center
    JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
    panelCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    panelCenter.add(jbn0);
    panelCenter.add(jbn1);
    panelCenter.add(jbn2);
    panelCenter.add(jbn3);
    panelCenter.add(jbn4);
    panelCenter.add(jbn5);
    panelCenter.add(jbn6);
    panelCenter.add(jbn7);
    panelCenter.add(jbn8);
    panelCenter.add(jbn9);
    panelCenter.add(jbKomma);
    panelCenter.add(jbnepo);


    //Main Panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(panelEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    //Frame
    GameWindow frame = new GameWindow("Lommeregner - "+randomMessage(), 315, 350);



    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    /*test.next();
    System.out.println(frame.size());*/




    //actionListeners

    //Numbers

    jbn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn0.value);
            tal = tal+jbn0.value;        //tal means number
        }});
    jbn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn1.value);
            tal = tal+jbn1.value;       //tal means number
        }});
    jbn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn2.value);
            tal = tal+jbn2.value;
        }});
    jbn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn3.value);
            tal = tal+jbn3.value;
        }});
    jbn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn4.value);
            tal = tal+jbn4.value;
        }});
    jbn5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn5.value);
            tal = tal+jbn5.value;
        }});
    jbn6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn6.value);
            tal = tal+jbn6.value;
        }});
    jbn7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn7.value);
            tal = tal+jbn7.value;
        }});
    jbn8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn8.value);
            tal = tal+jbn8.value;
        }});
    jbn9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbn9.value);
            tal = tal+jbn9.value;
        }});

    //operators

    jbKomma.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbKomma.name);
            tal = tal+jbKomma.name;
        }});

    jbnepo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = jtf.getText();
            if(tal.length() !=0 && minplu !=true && second == 0){
                System.out.println(first);
            minplu = true;
            jtf.setText("-"+tal);
            tal = "-"+tal;
            text = "";
            }else if(tal.length() != 0 && minplu == true && second == 0){
                minplu = false;
                tal = tal.substring(1, tal.length());
                System.out.println(tal);
                jtf.setText(text.substring(1, text.length()));
                text = "";
            }else if(tal.length() != 0 && minplu == true && second != 0){
                minplu = false;
                tal = tal.substring(1, tal.length());
                System.out.println(tal);
                jtf.setText(tal+text.substring(tal.length() - text.length(), text.length()));
                text = "";
            }

        }});

    jbPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jtf.getText().length() !=0){
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbPlus.getText());
            first = Float.parseFloat(tal);
            tal = "";
            operator = 1;
        }}});
    jbMinus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jtf.getText().length() !=0){
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbMinus.getText());
            first = Float.parseFloat(tal);
            tal = "";
            operator = 2;
            }}});
    jbGange.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jtf.getText().length() !=0){
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbGange.getText());
            first = Float.parseFloat(tal);
            tal = "";
            operator = 3;   
        }}});
    jbDivition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jtf.getText().length() !=0){
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbDivition.getText());
            first = Float.parseFloat(tal);
            tal = "";
            operator = 4;
            }}});
    jbErLigMed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jtf.getText().length() !=0){
            second = Float.parseFloat(tal);
            if(operator == 1)oper = first + second;
            if(operator == 2)oper = first - second;
            if(operator == 3)oper = first * second;
            if(operator == 4)oper = first / second;
            jtf.setText(jtf.getText()+jbErLigMed.getText()+oper);
            tal ="";
        }}});
    jbClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jtf.setText("");
            oper = 0;
            second = 0;
            first = 0;
            tal="";

        }});
    jbClearEntity.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = jtf.getText();
            if(tal.length() !=0)
            tal = tal.substring(0, tal.length() - 1);
            if(text.length() !=0)
            jtf.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
            System.out.println(tal);
        }});        
  }


  // random message i made for fun
  public static String randomMessage(){

    Random r = new Random();

    String[] message = {"17 * 17 = "+17*17, "What is 10 * 10??", "This is a calculator", "Have u found the secret spot yet??", "QUICK PRESS alt-F4!!!!", "Welcome", ""};

    int ri =r.nextInt(message.length - 1);

    return message[ri];
  }
}
```

**Button class:**

```
package me.lommeregner.main;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Button extends JButton{

  boolean operator;
  int value;
  String name;

  public Button(String name) {
    this.setText(name);
    this.name = name;
    operator = true;
  }

  public Button(String name, int value) {
    this.setText(name);
    this.value = value;
    operator = false;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public void setOperator(boolean operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  private boolean getOperator() {
    return operator;
  }
}
```

**GameWindow class:**

```
package me.lommeregner.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    public GameWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your post doesn't even contain all the code. Where's the GameWindow class defined?

Comment: Is `+/-` suppose to multiply the last entered digit with `-1`?

Comment: @DušanRychnovský I have added the gamewindow class now. i didn´t add it before because i didn´t think u needed it.

Comment: @Ian2thedv the +/- is suppose to make the last entered digits negative/posetive

Comment: Without making all the button variables final, the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @DušanRychnovský  do i need to make all the Button = new Button final??

Comment: If you want to access a local variable from within an inner class, you need to declare it as final. See how I updated you post.

Comment: @DušanRychnovský  ok thanks :D any other sugestions??

Answer (score 0):

Won't solve you actual problem, but here are some suggestions to better structure the code:

1. Don't call your class "Button". There is an AWT class of that name. Make your class more descriptive.
2. Don't use final variables.
3. Don't create the calculator in the main() method. The main() method should be used to create your calculator application. For example you might have a JPanel represent the calculator. Then all the variables/methods needed will be defined in the that class.
4. Some buttons (like 1, 2, 3, 4...) provide common  functionality so provide a common ActionListener so you don't need to duplicate the code 10 times.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField display;

    public CalculatorPanel()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
//              display.setCaretPosition( display.getDocument().getLength() );
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(30, 30) );
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text), text);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD" + text), text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new CalculatorPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, can u explain what this means:  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });

Comment: @Jonasm., all Swing components should be created/updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more information.